# MySQL doesn't use my defined index over a simple select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database-indexes

I've been trying to use an index in my query but to no avail. It's defined, but not used.

Here are my indexes

```
Table  | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
alerts |          1 | date_index |            1 | date        | A         |        9825 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE
```

This my query + explain:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT latitude, longitude, msg_id
        FROM alerts
        FORCE INDEX(date_index)
        WHERE date>1336312075;


| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | SIMPLE      | alerts | ALL  | date_index    | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9825 | Using where |
```

The table has 9825 rows, and the date I chose was among the latest 9.... so it should have scanned only 9 rows.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just a guess**: what is the type of your `date` column? Is it possible, that the value `1336312075` is not of type `date`? In this case the db may convert all values in the `date` column to the type of `1336312075` instead of converting `1336312075` to the type of `date` column which could render the index useless.

Possible solution: convert your value to the type of `date` column:

```
where date > convert_to_the_type_of_date_column(1336312075)
```